# The element is not shown using ng-if even the condition is true

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use `ng-if` to display/hide some elements in page, as follows:

```
<span ng-if="user.name == ''||user.name ==null">Name：No Data</span>
<span ng-if="user.name != ''&& user.name !=null" ng-bind="'Name：' + user.name"></span>
```

but these two elements are shown no matter `user.name` is set or not. I confirmed in the console of Chrome that the condition is true when running with debug mode.
It worked after I replaced `ng-if` with `ng-show`, I'm really confused with this.

Appreciated for any clarification. Thanks!

Update:

This is my `$scope.user`:

```
var u = {
    'loginId': mb,
    'mobile': mb.substr(0,3 ) + "****" + mb.substr(7, 11),
    'account': mb.substr(0,3 ) + "****" + mb.substr(7, 11),
    'score': data.score,
    'email': data.email,
    'name': data.name,
    'id': data.id
};
$scope.user = u;
```

Now I do have the value for `user.name`, I tried the suggestions provided below, this is my test result.

[image: The first one]

[image: The second one]

Comment: If the data is undefined, both the conditions will be success. So, use `===`. Which will solve your problem.

Comment: Can you share your user object?

Comment: We are asking for `user` object. See the object by using `console.log($scope.user)`.

Comment: This simply looks the case of incorrect user object.

Comment: @HassanImam Then why does it work with `ng-show`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the latest Angular version, it wasn't available in early versions of `~v1.0.1`

> AngularJS added the ngIf directive in `1.1.5`

**Working Demo**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.user = {
    name: "Rohit"
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <span ng-if="user.name == '' || user.name == null">Name：No Data</span>
  <span ng-if="user.name != '' && user.name != null" ng-bind="'Name：' + user.name"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: You are right, this is the least I considered. I'm always using the latest, but this is I got from my friend. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are using `==` to check equality which succeeds even if the data is undefined or some other data like that. So use `===` which will do your job.

All the best.

Comment: It's not working in my case, now I do have the value for `user.name`, but both elements shown.

Comment: var u = {
   'loginId': mb,
   'mobile': mb.substr(0,3 ) + "****" + mb.substr(7, 11),
   'account': mb.substr(0,3 ) + "****" + mb.substr(7, 11),
   'score': data.score,
   'email': data.email,
   'name': data.name,
   'id': data.id
  };

Comment: `var u`? You stored it in `$scope.user`?

Comment: Many thanks for all your help. The angular js is what I got from my friend, so I don't even think of the version. Thanks for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

This works well if `user.name` is `undefined`, `null` or `""`

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.user = {
    name: "xyz"
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <span ng-if="!user.name">Name：No Data</span>
  <span ng-if="user.name" ng-bind="'Name：' + user.name"></span>
</body>
```

Comment: I've tried this. It's really weird that not working for me.

Comment: Does it show you both elements? Update your question with the user object.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with undefined.
Remember that `null == undefined` but `null !== undefined`.

So when the property is undefined, both the conditions are shown.

Your condition can be only `ng-if="user.name"` or use strict equality ===

Answer (score 0):

Just check your condition:

```
<span ng-if="user.name">Name：No Data</span>
<span ng-if="!user.name" ng-bind="'Name：' + user.name"></span>
```

Since JavaScript evaluates to `false` when your `user.name` is: `null`, `0`, `""` (empty string), `NaN` or just `false`.

Works only if you are sure the variable was declared.

Comment: How is this different from my answer which i answered 10 mins ago?